# When attempting to migrate, Truffle (nodeJS) waffles between two errors?

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, truffle

I'm using truffle with a Node.js project, and when I attempt to migrate the project, I get the following error:
[Windows Script Host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIFIY.png)

However, when I use the suggested fix, which is to rename the truffle.js file to something other than truffle.js (i.e. truffle-config.js), then I get a different error:

```
Could not find suitable configuration file.
```

When I rename the configuration file back to "truffle.js", then I get the first error all over again.
The solutions I've tried have included using Windows Powershell to run the program and running the command `npm install --force -g truffle`, neither of which have worked. I've looked into the recommended solution (https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/150), and none of the proposed solutions have worked so far.

Comment: Same issues. Cannot get truffle to work following the official truffle installation instructions and petshop tutorial. I'd award a bounty for this question if I could.